# what is value of x for load and store

Tags: multithreading, compilation, load, store

This is some challenge

On a single processor system, in which load and store are assumed to be
atomic, what are all the possible values for x after both threads have completed in
the following execution, assuming that x is initialised to O? Hint: you need to
consider how this code might be compiled into machine language.

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) :
x = x + 1;

for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) :
x = x + 1;

Answer (score 1):

Each of the two lines in your question is meant to represent a separate thread. Since the shared variable `x` is not guarded, pretty much anything can happen. What are the possibilities you came up with? (otherwise I would feel like I'm just answering your problem for you)

SECOND HINT: Let a C compiler help you by showing you some examples...

```
int x;

void f(void)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)  x = x + 1;
}
```

(this is your program translated into C)

```
gcc -S -fno-PIC t.c
```

(this is what I have to type on my machine to get readable assembly)

```
_f:
pushl   %ebp
movl    %esp, %ebp
subl    $24, %esp
movl    $0, -12(%ebp)
jmp L2
L3:
movl    _x, %eax
incl    %eax
movl    %eax, _x
leal    -12(%ebp), %eax
incl    (%eax)
L2:
cmpl    $4, -12(%ebp)
jle L3
leave
ret
```

Now with optimizations (adding option -O2 to the compilation):

```
_f:
movl    _x, %eax
xorl    %edx, %edx
pushl   %ebp
movl    %esp, %ebp
.align 4,0x90
L2:
incl    %edx
incl    %eax
cmpl    $5, %edx
jne L2
movl    %eax, _x
leave
ret
```

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you don't need to consider all the possible sequences, you just need to consider the most extreme cases. What is the minimum value that x could possibly be ? And what is the maximum value that x could possibly be ?

The minimum case will occur when the loads for one thread always occur after a load and before a store in the other thread.

The maximum case will occur when there are no overlapping load-modify-store sequences.

That should be enough hints for you to work it out now.

Comment: I would argue that load r,x; r=r+42; store x,r; load r,x; r=r-37; store x,r; is a correct compilation for one of the threads with the information that has been made available to the compiler, and it gives a result higher than the "maximum case" you are thinking about, but that's pure nit-picking.

Comment: If the language was C and `x` was a `volatile` variable, then I would agree about non-overlapping sequences giving the maximum result for `x`.

Comment: @Pascal: true, but in the context of a noob-level homework question I think it's probably best to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Each thread will have 5 sets of the instructions:

```
LOAD X
INCREMENT X
STORE X
```

After each instruction the CPU can choose to yield execution two another thread.

- The very higherest X can become is
  10.This occurs when each thread finishes executing without yielding
  to the other.
- The lowest I could
  see  being is 5.  This is when first
  load instruction occurs on both
  threads, then one finishes execution,
  then the other finishes.

Answer (score -1):

well, most decent compilers will optimise that to `x=10;`

Comment: whats the reason? how did u get that?

Answer (score -1):

umm, 10.  Enlighten me otherwise.